# asp.net ajax updatepanel and playing sound

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I want to play a sound when asp.net updatepanel updates. Is there a free and simple way to play sound when ajax panel updates?

Answer (score 0):

Your going to have to attach an event to the endRequest event:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(EndRequestHandler);
```

the above is Asp.Net ajax, you will have to parse and determine if the postback is coming from a updatepanel's update.  The only true way to get a sound to play that is cross browser compatible is to trigger it within a Flash object.  IE and FF have different methods for firing a sound.

Comment: asp.net ajax updatepanel has and updateprogress template. Can I place the flash swf file to inside updateprogress template?

Comment: Thanks, Mike_G. My web app wil infrom the user with playing a sound when an update occures on a database table. I am trying to do it with asp.net ajax. the project will inform live http://live.feedjit.com does